# Show path tree with files

Tags: python, path, tree

```py
import os

path = "G:\krunker\mod"
abcde = open("path.txt", "w")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    directory_level = dirpath.replace(path, "")
    directory_level = directory_level.count(os.sep)
    indent = " " * 4
    print("{}{}/".format(indent*directory_level, os.path.basename(dirpath)), file=abcde)

for f in filenames:
        print("{}{}".format(indent*(directory_level+1), f), file=abcde)

abcde.close()
```

I want it to print the files in every single folder of the path but it does only on the last

Comment: Is that the original indentation? `for f in filenames:` has to be indented in order to be executed for every iteration of the loop. If it's not indented, it will only be executed once after the loop finishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indentation is not correct. The second `for` loop also has to be inside the first `for` loop.

**Correct code:**

```
import os

path = "/home/user/my_folder/tools"
abcde = open("path.txt", "w")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
    directory_level = dirpath.replace(path, "")
    directory_level = directory_level.count(os.sep)
    indent = " " * 4
    print("{}{}/".format(indent*directory_level, os.path.basename(dirpath)), file=abcde)

    for f in filenames:
            print("{}{}".format(indent*(directory_level+1), f), file=abcde)

abcde.close()
```

**A part of path.txt content:**

```
tools/
    .gitignore
    README.md
    __init__.py
    requirements3.txt
    test.py
    path.txt
    .git/
        description
        hooks/
            commit-msg.sample
        info/
            exclude
        refs/
            heads/
                master
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a recursive function which gets recursivly all subfolder's content until there's any subfolder:

```py
from os import walk

output = open("path.txt", "w")

def listFiles(path, indent):
    for (openedPath, folders, files) in walk(path):
        for file in files:
            output.write("\t" * (indent) + file + "\n")
        for folder in folders:
            output.write("\t" * (indent) + folder + "/\n")
            listFiles(path + "/" + folder, indent + 1)
        break

source = "/my/path/to/my/folder"
print(source + "/")
listFiles(source, 1)
```

There's an example with a little code project folder.

```
/my/path/to/my/folder/
        input.txt
        main.py
        output/
                error.cpp
                trying.cpp
                logo.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of code to simplify

```
import os
folder = r"C:\path\to\find\files"
x = [os.path.join(r,file) for r,d,f in os.walk(folder) for file in f # If you want specific files if file.endswith(".txt")]
y = [os.path.join(r,folder) for r,d,f in os.walk(folder) for folder in d]
print(x) #For files in main directory and subdirectories
print(y) #For files in main directory and subdirectories
```